# Deleting pointer causes heap corruption

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator, strcpy, heap-corruption

Could somebody explain why this code results in heap corruption?

```
string someText = "hello hello";
char **arrayOfCharPtr = new char*[5];
arrayOfCharPtr[0] = new char[someText.length()];
strcpy(arrayOfCharPtr[0], someText.c_str());
delete[] arrayOfCharPtr[0];
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your array is one character short, there's no space for the null character copied by `strcpy`.

Comment: Ok, length() + 1. But why does this cause a memory leak? the strcpy-line itself does not cause an error; it is the delete-line that causes it. Why can't it just delete whatever is in arrayOfCharPtr[0] regardless of how long its content is?

Comment: "the strcpy-line itself does not cause an error" Welcome to undefined behaviour, where things can seem to work but then blow up in spooky ways miles away from the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate one character more than the length of your string for storing the last '\0' character.

```
arrayOfCharPtr[0] = new char[someText.length()+1];
```

In your case the strcpy will write the last '\0' after the allocated bloc and it corrupts the heap.

Tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) can help to understand. valgrind produces the error message

```
==16970== Invalid write of size 1
==16970==    at 0x4C3106F: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16970==    by 0x400C47: main
==16970==  Address 0x5ab5cfb is 0 bytes after a block of size 11 alloc'd
==16970==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16970==    by 0x400C1C: main
```

which localizes the source of the error.